# How to understand/find sqoop code?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I always wonder how sqoop process parameters.For example we can pass -m 4 and --hive-import etc but none of the arguments are positional.How does Sqoop process all arguments.Does it creates a HashMap or ArrayList inside.Where can find all this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache sqoop is open source and it's source code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/sqoop).

You can `git clone` this project and debug test cases to understand code flow.

Meanwhile start with these classes to understand code:

- https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/7c1754270ff21f533088b946c873321f890da791/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/Sqoop.java#L91
- https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/7c1754270ff21f533088b946c873321f890da791/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/tool/SqoopTool.java
- https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/7c1754270ff21f533088b946c873321f890da791/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/SqoopOptions.java